# How to render external website home page in any specific part of my Angular 4 app page just like iframe

Tags: angular

Is there any way to render any external website home page in our Angular app home page just like we have done earlier using iframe in our asp.net websites? If yes, can someone please guide me or provide a solution?

Thanks

Comment: same iframe will work in angular

Comment: requirement is about not to use iframe. Need something else than iframe. Thanks

Comment: iframe is only option to display external site inside angular app. But alternatively you can open that external site in new tab using window.open(externalUrl, '_self') hope no more solution.